# jQuery Wookmark Plug-in API dosent work when the json loads from my server

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, wookmark

I am trying to work with the jQuery Wookmark Plug-in API, when I calling the original json from this URL 
http://www.wookmark.com/api/json/popular
it works fine

I copied the content and put it on my server on

```
http://13k.me/test.json
```

but it doesn't work

[Sample JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ccityweb/j686zx6e/4/)

Does somebody know the reason, do I miss somthing?

Comment: I don't think your jsfiddle runs right now, and it's got the wookmark URLs listed - can you correct it?

Comment: i fixed jsfiddle runs now